# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre REST y RESTful?

Tags: json, angularjs, nodejs

Entiendo que son arquitecturas y que la idea de estas es una ves descargado la página web esta no vuelva a descargar ningún HTML o CSS o JS si no, que solo haga llamadas o peticiones y sea respondido con JSON

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pVAMOielOJQ

Comment: @KristianDamian Es una pregunta muy genérica que no tiene por qué ser  una copia de las que mencionas. Además ninguna de las respuestas es del OP ni parece ser una traducción.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**REST** (Representational State Transfer) es una arquitectura que se ejecuta sobre HTTP.

**RESTful** hace referencia a un servicio web que implementa la arquitectura REST.

---

En un ejemplo bastante básico (de crear un aplicación RESTful), tenemos un proyecto donde implementamos un CRUD para casas en PHP y con la architectura MVC, el resultado de las respuestas serán devueltas en JSON, más no es obligatorio manejar sólo ese tipo `Content-type`, se puede devolver HTML, text, etc...

Mi modelo sería algo como:

```
namespace modelos\Casa;

use common\Model;

class Casa extends Model
{

    public function getId($id)
    {
        // Carga una casa por ID
        return ['id' => 1, 'puertas' => 1, 'focos' => 5];
    }

    public function getAll()
    {
        // Carga DB y devuelve todas las casas
        return [
            ['id' => 1, 'puertas' => 1, 'focos' => 5],
            ['id' => 2, 'puertas' => 1, 'focos' => 3],
            ['id' => 3, 'puertas' => 2, 'focos' => 8]
        ];
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        // Elimina un registro en la DB
        return parent::delete($id);
    }

    public function save()
    {
        // Valida que todo sea correcto y devuelve un booleano
        return parent::save();
    }

}
```

Mi controlador algo como:

```
namespace controladores\Casas;

use modelos\Casa;
use common\Controller;

header('Content-Type: application/json');

class Casas extends Controller
{

    public function actionPost($id)
    {
        $casa = Casa::findId($id);
        $casa->loadParams($_POST);

        echo json_encode(['success' => $casa->save()]);
    }

    public function actionGet($id = null)
    {
        if (isset($id)) {
            echo json_encode(Casa::getId($id));
        } else {
            echo json_encode(Casa::getAll());
        }
    }

    /* Aquí el demás código */

}
```

La 3a. parte podrías manejarla con JavaScript y HTML, donde el Js mandaría por medio de AJAX la petición para obtener un resultado y mostrarlo al usuario de forma amigable.

Las peticiones podrían realizarse a los recursos listados a continuación con el estado HTTP correspondiente y el controlador sería el encargado de responder a cada una de ellas.

[image: Tabla REST]

---

Información adicional en:

- http://es.slideshare.net/HctorFuentePrez/arquitectura-rest-42310133
- http://www.adwe.es/general/colaboraciones/servicios-web-restful-con-http-parte-i-introduccion-y-bases-teoricas
- http://inusual.com/articulos/rest-vs-soap-al-servicio-de-la-web/
- https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer

Comment: Gracias, me fue de mucha ayuda

Comment: Hola. Quiere decir que se puede mezclar MVC con REST? Y se podria decir entonces que usar REST es una cuestion de diseño.. O estilo arquitectonico

Comment: Si tengo mi aplicacion desarrollada en MVC como mostras vos: puedo usar REST? De hecho tengo mi app PHP con MVC.

Answer (score 5):

REST(Representational State Transfer o La Transferencia de Estado Representacional) es un estilo de arquitectura software, el cual no solo consiste en responder json, si no que también puede responder a otro formato de intercambio de datos como lo es xml.

Pero a parte de solo responder en un formato de intercambio que no sea HTML, REST involucra otros conceptos como:

- Recursos los cuales  pueden ser accedidos utilizando un identificador global (URI)
- Operaciones bien definidas para crear, leer, actualizar y eliminar
- Trabajar bajo un protocolo cliente-servidor sin estado, como lo es
  HTTP lo que significa que  cada mensaje HTTP contiene toda la
  información necesaria para comprender la petición.

REST es mucho más de lo que acabo de mencionar así que seria bueno que leyeras algo mas sobre que es realmente REST y no te quedes solo con la idea de que REST solo es para responder JSON a peticiones.

RESTful se suele utilizar para referirse a los servicios web que ejecutan la arquitectura REST.

Información adicional:

- http://hernandezblasantonio.bitbucket.org/hpw/documentacion/servidor/rest/
- https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer

Comment: Gracias fue de ayuda

Answer (score 2):

REST es un "estilo arquitectónico" que, básicamente, se aprovecha la tecnología y los protocolos de la Web existente.

RESTful se suele utilizar para referirse a los servicios web de ejecución de tal arquitectura.