# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre la API Fetch y la API Rest? , ¿Puedo utilizar Fetch en una Rest Api?

Tags: javascript, api, rest, fetch, peticiones

No creo tener bien claro los dos conceptos , ya los metodos de la API REST y Fetch API me parecen muy similares.

Comment: Imagina a REST como un centro de operaciones y fetch como una persona que llama a dicho centro :-). En términos más teóricos, REST es una interfaz para conectar varios sistemas basados en el protocolo HTTP y fetch es un método para hacer llamadas AJAX a la API REST, este es un tema un poco extenso pues deberías aprender a manejar la asincronía, promesas, etc

Comment: Creo que entiendo , estaría equivocado si digo que : FETCH AL IGUAL QUE AJAX SON TECNICAS O MECANISMOS PARA COMUNICARNOS A UNA API REST O BASE DE DATOS DE MANERA ASINCRONA?.

Answer (score 6):

#### Browser APIs

Son APIs del browser los distintos grupos de features con que el desarrollador de frontend puede interactuar. Engloban un conjunto muy acotado de clases, funciones, eventos, interfaces, tipos, etc cuyas responsabilidades tienen alta cohesión entre sí.

Toma por ejemplo en el [WebStorage API](https://whatwg.org/). Son sólo dos interfaces con un puñado de métodos, mapeadas a dos propiedades del objeto `window`. Tienen un propósito muy acotado y por ello tiene sentido "empaquetarlas" bajo la misma especificación funcional.

Hay un modelo de gobernancia para estas APIs, donde organizaciones como [Ecma International](https://whatwg.org/), [W3C](https://whatwg.org/) y [WhatWG](https://whatwg.org/) van "promulgando" las especificaciones funcionales y los browsers deben adherir a este contrato de interfaz para decir que "soportan" tal o cual API. Esto es a nivel de recomendación, claro, porque a veces se va incorporando ese soporte paulatinamente.

Si uno revisa en sitios como [Can I Use?](https://caniuse.com/geolocation) los browsers con soporte para un cierto API implementan la misma interfaz. No como antes en que un navegador podía tener

```
 window.objetoCualquiera.set(propiedad, valor)
```

y otro podría en cambio usar

```
 window.objetoCualquiera.put(propiedad,valor, callback(onError, onSuccess) {})
```

Así era antes y ambos decían soportar la funcionalidad, pero ese soporte era de facto y una pesadilla para el desarrollador.

Fetch API es una de esas APIs del browser. Propósito acotado, comportamiento homogéneo.

#### APIs en general

Así como hay APIs del browser también las hay disponibles en muchos otros ámbitos. Librerías que utilizas en la línea de comando o en tus programas tienen un API que expone ciertos métodos y encapsula el resto para que no sea problema tuyo. Las APIs que se acceden de manera remota son simplemente un API más.

Un sitio o servicio en general puede exponer un API para que los desarrolladores automaticen la interacción, con lo que sea que ofrecen, sin interacción humana. Cada uno puede implementar el API que se le de la gana, pero si mi API recibe mensajes mediante pings en clave morse no creo que tenga mucha adopción en la comunidad. Por lo mismo hay convenciones y el seguir una cierta convención es lo que determina si tu API es SOAP, REST, gRPC, GraphQL, etc.

Aunque semánticamente suena como si fueran grupos taxonómicos, eso no es tan así.

**SOAP** es un protocolo. Utiliza http como capa de transporte, los mensajes van estructurados en un XML, el servidor expone una interfaz con una serie de métodos que puedes invocar. Utiliza un lenguaje específico de dominio (WSDL) que describe tales interfaces y mediante el cual un cliente puede invocar los métodos como si se tratase de una instancia local.

**REST** también utiliza http como capa de transporte, pero no es un protocolo sino únicamente un patrón conceptual o arquitectural. Cuando se habla de REST se espera que el API siga la idea de fondo que *"Los verbos HTTP dictan el propósito de un llamado, y la URI del endpoint dicta el recurso afectado"*

- GET es para leer un recurso
- POST para crearlo
- DELETE para eliminarlo
- PUT para modificarlo pisando todas sus propiedades
- PATCH para modificarlo atómicamente, sólo algunas propiedades

Pero uno se encuentra con APIs que usan POST para casi todo y el propósito va en el URI. ej

```
  - POST /api/comment/33/delete
  - POST /api/comment/34/update 
    {"title": "título corregido"}
```

Hay estándares para definir la estructura de tu API (ej OpenAPI, RAML, etc) y hay estándares que describen la estructura de los mensajes (ej JSONAPI, oDATA), pero en realidad hay APIs que son el fruto de un desarrollador inspirado e igual se consideran RESTFul

**GraphQL** le traspasa al cliente la responsabilidad de interactuar con las entidades. El servidor expone un recurso o un pequeño conjunto de recursos y el cliente arma una query, lo cual conceptualmente podría compararse a lo que ocurre cuando armas una query SQL y la mandas a la base de datos.

**gRPC** usa HTTP2 como capa de transporte pero, a diferencia de los otros, no es texto lo que va y viene, sino protocol buffers, binarios.

Un servicio puede tener más de un API, tanto para efectos de versionamiento como para exponer más de un tipo de los mencionados. Por ejemplo Github APIv3 es REST. Github API v4 es GraphQL.

Perfectamente podrías encontrar en la descripción de un flujo algo como:

- Este programita utiliza Fetch API para enviar un request a Github API
- No soportamos GraphQL, así que recuerden usar el API Rest de Github API
- Las respuestas del API Rest de Github API no cumplen con JSONAPI
- La definición del API Rest de Github API [está disponible en formato OpenAPI](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/openapi-description)

Answer (score 5):

Creo que tienes una confusión importante: Fetch es un API disponible en el navegador, una serie de funcionalidades implementadas para hacer llamadas HTTP asíncronas.

REST es un *estilo arquitectural*, una guía para diseñar APIs. Por tanto no es un API. Puedes encontrar más detalles en [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76615/qu%C3%A9-diferencia-hay-entre-soap-y-rest?rq=1) o en esta [otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2512/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-rest-y-restful)